# How to name a list object in R

Tags: r, list, labeling

In R the objects of the list itself [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3qO9.png)], [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9A5o.png)] and [[3]] can't seem to be renamed. See:

```
my_df1 <- mtcars[1:10,]
my_df1 <- mtcars[11:20,]
my_df1 <- mtcars[21:30,]
my_list <- list(my_df1, my_df2, my_df3)
```

This gives me the following:
[image]

Is there a way to rename the [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3qO9.png)] objects themselves?
I find this a drawback of R.
I am dealing with categories of data and want to be sure which category I am dealing with by labelling each object. Thanks

Comment: Try: `list(a=my_df1, b=my_df2, c=my_df3)`

Comment: or `names(my_list)[1] <- "a"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to name the lists while creating them you can use `tibble::lst`

```
my_df1 <- mtcars[1:10,]
my_df2 <- mtcars[11:20,]
my_df3 <- mtcars[21:30,]
my_list <- tibble::lst(my_df1, my_df2, my_df3)
```

If the list is already created you can use `names` or `setNames` to name the list.

```
names(my_list) <- c('list1', 'list2', 'list3')

setNames(my_list, c('list1', 'list2', 'list3'))
```

Comment: Or `structure` which avoids a dependency on the stats package

Comment: Doing setNames(my_list[[1]], labels[1]) to just set the name of the first object, does not work.

Comment: Use `my_list[1] <- setNames(my_list[1], labels[1]) `

Comment: Ok, I realized my real life example is different. So I will open a new issue. Thanks. This works in this case.